# In SystemVerilog are indexing a parameter array in a for loop a constant expression

Tags: system-verilog

The following modules tries to use an unpacked parameter array in three different ways.

```
module works
  #(parameter int num = 4,
    parameter int width = 8,
    parameter int bits [num] = '{4, 4})
   (output logic [width-1:0] mask [num]);

    genvar i;
    generate
        for(i=0; i<num; ++i) begin
            always_comb mask[i] = {{(width-bits[i]){1'b0}},{bits[i]{1'b1}}};
        end
    endgenerate
endmodule

module also_works
  #(parameter int num = 4,
    parameter int width = 8,
    parameter int bits [num] = '{4, 4})
   (output logic [width-1:0] mask [num]);

    always_comb begin
        mask[0] = {{(width-bits[0]){1'b0}},{bits[0]{1'b1}}};
        mask[1] = {{(width-bits[1]){1'b0}},{bits[1]{1'b1}}};
        mask[2] = {{(width-bits[2]){1'b0}},{bits[2]{1'b1}}};
        mask[3] = {{(width-bits[3]){1'b0}},{bits[3]{1'b1}}};
    end
endmodule

module fails
  #(parameter int num = 4,
    parameter int width = 8,
    parameter int bits [num] = '{4, 4})
   (output logic [width-1:0] mask [num]);

    always_comb begin
        for(int i=0; i<num; ++i) begin
            mask[i] = {{(width-bits[i]){1'b0}},{bits[i]{1'b1}}};
        end
    end
endmodule
```

The first two modules are considered correct by the simulator I am using. However the last one is considered to not correct since `i` is not a constant expression. However the only way I can semantically interpret the for loop in the always block version is the same as `also_works`.

I could not find anything in the standard that clarifies this situation, expect what is stated in Section 11.2.1

> **11.2.1 Constant expressions**
>
> Some statement constructs require an expression to be a constant
>   expression. The operands of a constant expression consist of constant
>   numbers, strings, parameters, constant bit-selects and part-selects of
>   parameters, constant function calls (see 13.4.3), and constant system
>   function calls only. Constant expressions can use any of the operators
>   defined in Table 11-1.

As far as I can see it only talks about bit and part-selects and not about indexing parameter arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When replicating with `{repNum{val}}` syntax, `repNum` needs to be a constant. `bits[i]` is not a a constant because the index is dynamic in simulation. The `generate` works because the loop is static unrolled during compile/elaboration.

You can do bit assignment to get the same functionality:

```
always_comb begin
  foreach(mask[i,j]) begin
    mask[i][j] = (j<bits[i]);
  end
end
```

Comment: I still do not see how the dynamic index has anything to do with if ``repNum`` is constant or not. It indexes into an array of constants.

Comment: The array as a whole is constant, but the code is selecting an instance of the array. Verilog runs for-loops inside an procedural block as dynamical in simulation; it doesn't matter if it would be safe to static unroll. `bits[i]` in is is indeterminate at time 0 because `i` is dynamic; therefore `bits[i]` is dynamic even though `bits` is static.

Comment: Then I guess SystemVerilog is broken in yet another way ;). The statical unrolling is the only thing that makes sense for synthesis. It seams that SV's entire concept of constant expressions is flawed in its current form.